# (How) can I make an on-topic question from this?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I posted [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52728/searching-for-a-rhythm-in-weight-loss-gain) on Software Recommendations. As it is getting no response, I think that I might try to make a meaningful chart for my friend, in Excel .

Actually, I would prefer someone else to post an Excel formula to do so, but that is certainly off-topic here.

What I am hoping is not off topic is asking for a mathematical formula which will produce meaningful results.

From that question:

> Basically my friend weighs daily and has historical data in CSV format. They would like a gratis app that takes that data and overlays it in some form of weekly chart. E.g shows only Monday to Sunday (start day preferably selectable), not several months or years.
>
> We are unsure what format the display should take, but the objective is to see if there is a pattern to weight loss/gain on certain days of the week.
>
> My friend has been steadily losing weight for months now, but against that background, there are days when weight is gained and my friend is looking for an identifiable pattern. A very obvious example would be weight gain on Monday after a weekend binge, but this is not the case, just an example.
>
> The idea is that if certain days can be identified as problematic then the cause can be identified and behavio(u)r changed.

So, could I somehow phrase that to be an on-topic question here? I am looking for a pattern in data (and how best to represent it visually).

Comment: It already looks good to me.

Comment: I might remove the phrase about a gratis app just in case that triggers rejection as a code request but otherwise looks fine.

Comment: To me to - data visualization & exploratory analysis is certainly on topic.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. I always find it better to ask on meta or in chat before posting for the first time on a new site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering it so it does not stay unanswered: this was on-topic as is.

PS. This question was asked and received a great answer: [Searching for a weekly rhythm in weight loss/gain](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372561).

Comment: Martijn's answer in the linked Q does not have enough upvotes! Take a look.